# How to implement dynamic arrays in C?

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

I am writing this code using dynamic memory allocation, for student records as indicated, this code suppose to be simple , I am obviously allocating elements in their correct places the right way, but when it comes to printing them, it gives me a "`core dumped`" error ! what is wrong ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    char **firstname;
    char **lastname;
    float *score;
    int number_of_records,i,j,ctr=1,row=15,col=20;
    /*ctr is to keep track of the student's number (makes it easier to
      the user), it starts with (1)*/

    firstname=malloc(row*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        firstname[i]=malloc((col+1)*sizeof(char));
    }
     lastname=malloc(row*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        lastname[i]=malloc((col+1)*sizeof(char));
    }
    printf("\nPlease indicate number of records you want to enter (min 2, max 15): ");
    scanf("%d",&number_of_records);
    score=malloc(row*sizeof(float));

    printf("\nPlease input records of students\n(enter a new line after"
           "each record), with following format:\nfirst name last name score ");
    for (i=0;i<number_of_records;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter record for student %d : ",ctr);
        scanf("%s %s %f",firstname[i],lastname[i],score[i]);

        ctr++; /*ctr is to keep track of student number
                 (makes it easy to the user) */

    }
     for (i=0;i<number_of_records;i++)
    {

        printf("%s %s %f\n",firstname[i],lastname[i],score[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change this:

```
for (i=0;i<number_of_records;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter record for student %d : ",ctr);
        scanf("%s %s %f",&firstname[i],&lastname[i],&score[i]);

        ctr++; /*ctr is to keep track of student number (makes it easy to the       user) */
    }
```

to this

```
for (i=0;i<number_of_records;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter record for student %d : ",ctr);
        scanf("%s %s %f",firstname[i],lastname[i],&score[i]);

        ctr++; /*ctr is to keep track of student number (makes it easy to the       user) */
    }
```

And it will work. The reason is that `firstname[i]` and `lastname[i]` are already `pointers`; you do not need to use `&` operator for them.

P.S. Also, since you are using C, do no cast the returning values from `malloc` or `realloc`. It will be done automatically.

Comment: Removing the & gives me a "core dumped" error at the time of inputting the information.

Comment: For reasons why the return value of `malloc()` shouldn't be casted, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3488231

Comment: i removed casting before malloc(), It did not help.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I found this error: `int number_of_records,i,j,ctr=1,row=15,col=20,;` (remove that comma before the semicolon. Afterwards I only changed what I posted above and it worked fine for me..

Comment: This comma was typing error here on stack-flow, not in the compiler, sorry i'll edit it out, the compiler I am using is Code:: Blocks

Comment: @aero Can you give us the exact input you tried that triggered the error? So far I am not reproducing it.

Comment: Suppose i choose 2 records, the first line :jack moore 98 , the second line : mike blackbird 88

Comment: I'm not getting an error. Please edit your question and add your current code, in case you have done any accidental changes.

Comment: @naltipar what compiler are you not getting an error with ?

Comment: @ace , because it did not make a difference , however i just did, same result , in fact when i remove the & i get an error once i enter the info.

Comment: @aero Read the answer carefully. Remove `&` for `firstname[i]` and `lastname[i]` but not `score[i]`.

Comment: @naltipar , sorry i didn't pay close attention to (score) , thanks for help.